# listview with checkbox single clickable

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

i have a listivew with custom arrayadapter and custom layout, it have a Checkbox.
I want to make this listview only one checkbox enabled but i dont know how can i do it.

This is my adapter, but the check and uncheck dont works fine. Any exmple please.

```
public class gremioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Gremio> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Gremio> data = null;
protected String comentarioAlEdiText;

public gremioAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Gremio> data)
{
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

public void updateDataSet(Gremio objetoGremioAnadir) {
    this.data.add(objetoGremioAnadir);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void updateDataSet(Gremio objetoGremioAnadir, int posicion) {
    this.data.add(posicion, objetoGremioAnadir);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void updateDataSet(String comentario, int posicion) {
    this.data.get(posicion).comentario = comentario;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
public void updateDataSet() {

    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    GremioHolder holder = null;
    final GremioHolder h2 = holder;


    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new GremioHolder();
        holder.tvGremio = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvGremio);
        holder.cbActivo = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cbGremioActivo);
        holder.tvComentario = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvComentario);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (GremioHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Gremio gremioFinal = data.get(position);

    holder.tvGremio.setText(gremioFinal.literal);
    holder.tvComentario.setText(gremioFinal.comentario);

    if (data.get(position).getActivo().equals("1")) {
        holder.cbActivo.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        holder.cbActivo.setChecked(false);
    }

    holder.cbActivo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (data.get(position).activo.equals("0"))
                h2.cbActivo.setChecked(true);
            if (data.get(position).activo.equals("1"))
                h2.cbActivo.setChecked(false);

        }
    });
    holder.cbActivo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (!isChecked) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                        data.get(i).activo = "0";
                    }
                    data.get(position).activo = "1";
                }
                if (isChecked) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                        data.get(i).activo = "0";
                    }
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    public class GremioHolder {
        TextView tvGremio;
        CheckBox cbActivo;
        TextView tvComentario;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to make it mutually exclusive? ie, if you check one checkbox the others should be unchecked?

Comment: use toggle Button instead of checkbox and create selector xml file in drawable folder.rather than using arrayAdapter use BaseAdapter,which will be easy to implement

Comment: @Shubhayu Yes, if i check one, the others be unchecked.

Comment: @AkashG I need to use arrayadapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take care of your requirement. A very good tutorial on how you can achieve this.

http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/

So the basic funda is that,

1. Extend a Layout (Linear/Relative) and implement the checkable interface.
2. After inflating the layout, find out which child was selected and check the corresponding checkbox. Uncheck any other previously checked item.
3. Make sure that your ListView's XML has the following marked [android:choiceMode="singleChoice"]

Comment: Please don't just link outside Stackoverflow without any kind of explanation or summary. Elaborate a little. =)

Comment: Point taken :) Hope it is not plagiarism though :P

Comment: No, that would be blatantly ripping a whole article and passing it off as your own. Quoting is permitted under most copyright laws. =)

Answer (score 0):

hop it is useful to you...
just change in your getview() method .

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final Holder holder;
        if (vi == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_customelabel_list, null);
            holder = new Holder();

            holder.txtname = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.raw_customlabel_txt_name);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.raw_customlabel_checkbox);
            vi.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (Holder) vi.getTag();
        }

        vi.setTag(holder);
        holder.txtname.setText(strarry[position]);

        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < strarry.length; i++) {
                    if (v.getId() == i) {
                        checkarry[i] = true;
                        Log.v("check", ""+position);
                    } else {
                        checkarry[i] = false;
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        if (checkarry[position]) {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }

        return vi;
    }

}
```